# How do I "activate Alliance network" to play multiplayer in the demo?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When I try to play multiplayer in the ME3 demo, I get this message:

> ### Error
>
> You do not yet have access to the online features of the Mass Effect 3 demo.  Please try again later.

Back on the main screen there is this scrolling text:

> Activate Alliance Network to Access Online Features

How do I do that?  All I can find is speculation that it requires DLC or that [you need to wait until the game is released](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995487-mass-effect-3/61969814), but obviously it's already been released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah fudge, I post this and then I see some more scrollage:

> Multiplayer demo is now closed.  Single Player demo still active.

That's kind of lame.  Does anyone know how long it was open for?

**Edit:** Found that too.  [February 17th to March 5th](https://help.ea.com/uk/article/mass-effect-3-demo-faq).